# Status bar overlay Toolbar after repacing a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

My Activity has 2 Fragments, and each of them using a private toolbar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I implemented the translucent toolbar for them by using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

On the first fragment, it worked normally as I expected. On the second one, the  toolbar was overlaid under status bar.

[image]
[image]

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BlankFragment  a = new BlankFragment ();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, a).commit();

    }
```

FragmentBlank

```
@OnClick({R.id.btnNext})
    public void moveToFragment2(){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        BlankFragment2 ab = new BlankFragment2();
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, ab).commit();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

you can add to your fragments

```
 getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
```

and match the toolbar color.

Another alternative is to set the app to be fullscreen but you will lose the status bar and if i am right you want the status bar. The code is this:

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute in the root `ViewGroup`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```